# Extract a mysql resource to php array?

Tags: php, mysql

My goal is to display the profile of a user. I have this function:

```
function get_profile($un) {
            if($registerquery = $this->conn->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE usr = '".$un."' ")){
               return $profile = mysql_fetch_array($registerquery); 
           }
        }
```

Then the display snippet:

```
<?php $profile = $mysql->get_profile($un); 

foreach($profile as $key => $value){

     echo "<span>".$key.': '.$value."</span><br />"; 

  }

?>
```

But I get: "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in..."

Help pls???

Comment: return value from get_profile?

Comment: there probably should be something in this `there should be somthing here` place ;)

Comment: @Lukas: Just edited it. Sorry..

Comment: @darma and @Joann, I stand corrected, I was not paying attention.

Comment: Have you tried just returning `mysql_fetch_array` opposed to `$profile = mysql_fetch_array`?

Comment: What does your `$this->conn->query()` method return? Does it return a MySQL resource or an array or what?

Comment: @Scott: a resource. The return line extracts it into an array and assigns the result to $profile. But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Unrelated, you should use `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: @Anthony: Same result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to see if the result was a success or not

```
if (gettype($result) == "boolean") {
    $output = array('success' => ($result ? 1 : 0));
}
```

And you need to cycle through it if it's a resource type...

```
if (gettype($result) == "resource") {
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0 ) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $output[] =$row;
        }
    }
}
```

I chopped up some real code that does basically everything pretty awful for you because I can't release it, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Check the result of `get_profile`, as it will return `null` if the query failed. You can't loop over `null`.

Comment: Yah it's null. I suspect the problem is the "return" line. The assignment doesn't assign anything...

Comment: Assigning the result to `$profile` doesn't do anything as you didn't declare `global $profile` in your function, just return the result directly instead and capture the value. The problem must be somewhere in your `MySQL->conn->query` function.

Comment: This how I got the "conn". It's a new instance of mysqli.  private $conn;
 
 function __construct() {
  $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER_USERS, DB_USER_USERS, DB_PASSWORD_USERS, DB_NAME_USERS) or 
       die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');
 }

Comment: Add an `else` statement to the `get_profile` function to alert if the query failed. A bad query would also cause your function to return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with Anthony Forloney. The following code is just returning TRUE or FALSE depending on wether loading the `$profile` variable worked:

```
return $profile = mysql_fetch_array($registerquery);
```

You don't need `$profile`.  You can eliminate it as such:

```
return mysql_fetch_array($registerquery);
```

The function will return the array and then when you call the function later you can load it's return value into `$profile` as you do with the following:

```
$profile = $mysql->get_profile($un);
```

Comment: Tried it didn't work. Tried to echo $profile, nothing shows up, so the function returns a null.

Comment: Yes, I think you're query is returning nothing then. Try a simple query like `SELECT 1,2,3` to see if the rest of your function is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Be very very careful here. You are passing a raw string into the query function without escaping it and without using a parameterized query. Use mysql_escape_string around $un in your query. Your code flaw is called a sql injection attack.

Someone could pass their username as this

```
myusername'; update users set password = '';
```

And blank all passwords, thereby allowing themselves to access any account. Other similar shady attacks are equally likely.. you can basically do anything to a database with sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function get_profile($un) {
    if($result = $this->conn->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE usr = '".$un."' ")){
        return $result->fetchArray(MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
    }
    return array();
}
```

You're mixing MySQLi and MySQL functions and you can't do that. And, the last line of this code will return an empty array if the query does not work, rather than return null.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably empty ($profile). Print the value of "count($profile)"

Answer (score -1):

I have found that the easiest way to loop through mysql results is to use a while loop:

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
$result = mysql_query($select);
while ($profile = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $name = $profile['name'];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Make sure you wrap your array keys in single quotes, otherwise it will search for a constant first then revert to 'name' - considered very bad practice. Also much better to utilize MySQLi methods instead of just vanilla MySQL functions

Comment: Interesting. What are MySQLi functions? I do like improving my code whenever I can.

I do use single quotes, except when the I'm calling the array key inside of a set of double quotes. Is it bad practice to leave out the single quotes in that case, as well?